# Function in PHP is not working

Tags: php

**Code:**

```
<?php

include('core/settings.php');
include('core/connection.php');

function getInvoice($n, $conn) 
{ 
   $stid = oci_parse($conn, '

     SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = $n

   ');
   oci_execute($stid);

   $result = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH);
   echo $result;
} 

getInvoice(1050505);

?>
```

I am not shown the results of `getInvoice` when visiting this page. The manual SQL works ok. Is there a problem here in the PHP that I am using?

**Edit 1:** If there is a simpler method to do this then please suggest it. The SQL result is a simple number for example:

```
InvoiceNo
---------

1050505
```

**Edit 2:** I have updated `functions.php` and put it below.

```
<?php

function getInvoice($n) 
{ 
   include('connection.php');

   $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = '.$n);
   oci_execute($stid);

   $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH);
   echo $row['0'];
} 

?>
```

The `getInvoice` works if I use it within that file, but when I try and use this in another file, it doesn't return anything.

```
<? php

  include('core/functions.php');

  getInvoice(1050505);

?>
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the connection.

Comment: you are missing the 2nd param `getInvoice(1050505);`

Comment: You're currently assuming all the statements executed without any troubles. ***Always*** check for return values. `var_dump()` variables. [**Enable error reporting**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393).

Answer (score 2):

Make a change in SQL query as '' doesn't recognise $n(take it as string not variable)

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = $n");
```

And Pass seconds parameter to function call.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the **second parameter** in function and you need to change the query

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = '.$n);
```

Use this code for enable error reporting

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```